# How to restrict values of an argument in Prolog using a series of facts?

Tags: prolog

I want to restrict the query `property(X, use, Y)` to values of `Y` in the list `[a,b,c]`.
`c/1` is true for only those values of `Y`.
I thought the following would work, but it doesn't.

```
c(a).
c(b).
c(c). 

property(X, use, Y).
c(Y).
```

The following statements yield only `false`.

```
     person(1).
     property(1, use, _).
```

I'm using Problog, but I'm not using any Problog functions here, so I think I am misunderstanding something about unification.

I thought `c(Y)` would generate the list and `Y` would be unified across the facts.

**Update**
This does seem to be an Problog-specific issue as the following illustrates.

```
substance(methadone). 
substance(heroin).

P::property(X,use,nicotine) :-  %doesn't work
    property(X,use,Z),
    substance(Z),
    P is 0.8.

property(X,use,nicotine) :-  %works
    property(X,use,Z),
    substance(Z).

person(1).
substance(Y).
property(1, use, Y).
```

Comment: `person(1)` yields false because there is no rule (perforce no fact) concerning any `person/1`. On the other hand, `property(1,use,_)` should succeed as it unifies with `property(X,use,Y)`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write:

```
property(_X, use, Y) :-
    c(Y).
```