# Why does this give a NonGroundProbabilisticClause error, but not the deterministic counterpart?

Tags: prolog, problog

I want the program to represent that if *person 1 uses one out of a particular list of substances then there is an 80% chance that person uses nicotine*.

As in the example below, I have defined `substance/1` to be true only for a few atoms.

What explains the difference in behavior between the two versions of `property/3`? The probabilistic version does not seem to have the issues discussed in [Problogs FAQs](https://problog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html).

```
substance(methadone). 
substance(heroin).

P::property(X,use,nicotine) :-  %gives  NonGroundProbabilisticClause error
    property(X,use,Z),
    substance(Z),
    P is 0.8.

property(X,use,nicotine) :-  %appropriately infers nicotine use
    property(X,use,Z),
    substance(Z).
    
person(1).
substance(Y).
property(1, use, Y).

query(property(1,use, nicotine)).
```

**Update**

Discussion with @2bigpips brings out a related issue. Assigning a probability at the head of a probabilistic clause doesn't mean that you are clamping the probability at that value. This is important to realize if you are linking the probabilities to estimated quantities, for example, from experiments.

Comment: Could you tell us what you want the program to mean?
Currently, `substance(Y)` means everything is a substance, and `property(1, use, Y).` means 1 uses everything (whether Y is a substance, a person or bad analogies)

Comment: @2bigpigs added.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood. I've edited my answer

Comment: Regarding your update: I'm not sure what you mean by clamping, but it does do it in some way. Say you observed that the person uses nicotine `
evidence(property(1, use, nicotine)).`, And you had some weak prior on the use of other substances:
`0.01::property(X, use, methadone).` and 
`0.001::property(X, use, heroin).`

Querying the probabilities of using methadone or heroin would answer much larger numbers ( 0.090 & 0.90 instead of  0.01 and 0.001 )

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Deterministic clauses and probabilistic clauses have different semantics. Long answer in part 2.

**Part 1: What your program means**

```
substance(Y).        % means everything is a substance.
property(1, use, Y). % means: 1 uses everything (whatever 1 is)
```

As indicated in [Paulo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65862228/1115433) to your previous question, the scope of the variable is limited to the clause. The Y in these facts are not the same variable. From a logic perspective, you have 2 separate clauses:

```
(\forall Y: substance(Y))
 (\forall Z: person(1, use, Z))
```

His suggestion will work and means person 1 uses all substances.
substance(methadone).
substance(heroin).

```
substance(methadone). 
substance(heroin).


0.8::property(X,use,nicotine) :-  %gives  NonGroundProbabilisticClause error
    property(X,use,Z),
    substance(Z).

% person(1).
% property(1, use, Y):- substance(Y). % person1 uses all substances

query(property(1,use, nicotine)).
% property(1,use,nicotine):       0.96
```

**EDIT after seeing what you meant**
Since you want it to be 0.8 whether uses 1 or many substances, you can just do this:

```
argument-in-prolog-using-a-series-of-facts
substance(methadone). 
substance(heroin).

0.8::property(X,use,nicotine) :- 
    uses_atleast_one_substance(X).

uses_atleast_one_substance(X):-
    property(X,use,Z),
    substance(Z).


person(1).
property(1, use, Y):- substance(Y).

query(property(1,use, nicotine)).
```

**Part 2: What's happening**

I have to make a guess here: The non-probabilistic clause may work because it's non-probabilistic and hence not an annotated-disjunction. It may have prolog-like semantics.

Probabilistic clauses follow the semantics of annotated disjunctions. Every probabilistic clause is implicitly an annotated disjunction -
`p::head:- body.` is `p::head ; (1-p)not_head:- body.`

Here's a paper with the semantics of "[Logic Programs with Annotated Disjunctions](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.69.6404)".
It says every grounding of the body independently causes the head to be true with the specified probability.

With that in mind, The reason you're getting the error is because there is indeed a non-ground BODY in the proof.

```
P::property(X,use,nicotine) :-  %gives  NonGroundProbabilisticClause error
    property(X,use,W), % This can unify with person(1,use,Z), leaving Z free
    substance(Z),      % This can unify with substance(Y), leaving Z free
    P is 0.8.
```

You can't have variables in the body because you don't know how many causes there are. It breaks the semantics and problog detects it and throws an error. That's what's happening.

Comment: The ProbLog creators simultaneously provided a similar explanation on their Git (https://github.com/ML-KULeuven/problog/issues/54#issuecomment-766322848). Why does the head have probability 0.96, not 0.8?

Comment: Because there are two explanations for the user to use nicotine - because he uses heroine or because he uses methadone. Each of them independently try to make the nicotine use true. You're essentially tossing 2 biased coins - If you have atleast one head, it means he uses nicotine.

This tutorial from them may help: https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/problog/tutorial/basic/08_rule_probs.html

Comment: I get what you mean though. Let me try to come up with that version instead.